# PyCharm - Add "-O" flag to configuration

Tags: pycharm, compiler-flags

I'd like to create a "release" configuration in PyCharm for my script, such as the call command is:

python -O myscript.py

Where can I set the "-O" flag inside a configuration setting?

Answer (score 2):

Make a "Run Configuration". In the configuration options, there is a field "Interpreter options:". In there, supply -O. When you run the run configuration, the -O will be just after the Python command.