# How apply optimization flag for run but not debug for default configurations?

Tags: python, pycharm

I would like to modify the default run (not debug) behavior in Pycharm to include the `-O` flag, as indicated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75384534/6251742).

The information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211994/pycharm-add-o-flag-to-configuration) on creating a run configuration is helpful, but I have many files with `if __name__ == "__main__"` blocks that I need to run locally, and I would like Pycharm to automatically execute them with the `-O` option during a "run". The debug behavior should remain unchanged and the `-O` flag shouldn't be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## -O for run but not Debug

You can't do that with configuration but:

### Use External tool Pycharm feature

You can configure an external tool configuration (settings>Tools>"External Tools">Add) like this:
[image: edit external tool pycharm panel]

Then, you can assign a shortcut in keymap to run this configuration that will run Python with optimization flag on the current file.
[image: keymap setting panel]

## -O for default configuration (both run/debug)

### Use `Run/Debug configurations>Edit configuration templates`

You can't choose a configuration based on the content of a file (or not easily) or change options if it is run or debug, but you can change the default template used for configuration to include the `-O` flag in the interpreter options.

[image: Pycharm run/debug configuration template panel]

Comment: this seems to apply to both Run and Debug. Can I have `-O` just for run? it puzzles how this cannot be the default setting actually.

Comment: I edited the answer to add this possibility.